# Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module error when integrating intl-tel-input with mageto2

Tags: magento2, javascript

I am trying to use https://github.com/jackocnr/intl-tel-input with magento2 on customer registration form for mobile number field to show country flag for choosing phone number but i am getting error `"Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module..."`

I have followed some tutorials and my js is being added and its working fine but in browser console i get above mentioned error
Content of `module_name/view/frontned/requirejs-config.js` are:

```
var config = {
map: {
    '*': {
        intlTelInput: "Vendor_Module/js/plugin/intlTelInput.min",
    }
},
"shim": {
    intlTelInput: "Vendor_Module/js/plugin/intlTelInput.min"
   }
};
```

Sometimes this works and sometimes it does not works. By not working i mean to say that sometimes flags appears on input field sometime it does not but console is showing error everytime i refresh or open this page.
For more info i am attaching the screenshot.

[image]

Thank you for the help.